# Is it possible to have two if statements control conditional logic

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to have two separate input fields control a show/hide logic jointly.

```
$("#QuestionNumber1").change(function() { 
    if($(this).val() == "Yes") { 
        $("tr.hidden1").show(); 
    } 
    else {
        $("tr.hidden1").hide();
    }
});
```

I'd like to add a secondary question to the above code so that if both QuestionNumber1 is "Yes" and QuestionNumber2 is "Yes" then show "hidden1". Is that possible?

Comment: This is basics of the language.  You should not have had to post a S.O. question to find this information.  Many resources already exist on the web related to javascript and chaining conditionals.

Comment: I'm really sorry. I had searched for a while and tested and wasn't able to make it work. I appreciate the help. I will spend more time, next time, searching before submitting a question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
if($('#QuestionNumber1').val() == "Yes" && $('#QuestionNumber2').val() == "Yes")
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a handler to both inputs, and have the handler check both inputs' values:

```js
$("#QuestionNumber1, #QuestionNumber2").change(function() {
  $("tr.hidden1").toggle(
    $('#QuestionNumber1').val() === 'Yes' && $('#QuestionNumber2').val() === 'Yes'
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="QuestionNumber1">
<input id="QuestionNumber2">
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="hidden1" style="display: none;"><td>some tr</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```